# HTTP_REFERER syntax

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite

I'm using this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(subdomain\.)?domain\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx|mp4|mov|mp3) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx|mp4|mov|mp3)$ https://subdomain.domain.com/ [NC]
```

about `https://(subdomain\.)?domain\.com/` is the correct syntax to refer

> http://subdomain.domain.com/
>   http://www.subdomain.domain.com/
>   https://subdomain.domain.com/
>   https://www.subdomain.domain.com/

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
^https?://(www\.)?subdomain\.domain\.com/
```

> EXPLANATION:
>
> `^` asserts position at start of the string
>
> `http` matches the characters http literally
>
> `s` - matches the character s literally
>
> `?` - quantifier, matches character "s" between zero and one times
>
> `://` - matches the characters :// literally
>
> `www` - matches the characters www literally
>
> `\.` - matches the character "." literally
>
> `?` - quantifier, matches group "www." between zero and one times
>
> `subdomain` - matches the characters "subdomain" literally
>
> `\.` - matches the character "." literally
>
> `domain` - matches the characters "domain" literally
>
> `\.` - matches the character "." literally
>
> `com/` - matches the characters "com/" literally

https://regex101.com/r/TcOZuw/1

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?subdomain\.domain\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx|mp4|mov|mp3) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx|mp4|mov|mp3)$ https://subdomain.domain.com/ [NC]`

Referring for
`http://subdomain.domain.com/
http://www.subdomain.domain.com/
https://subdomain.domain.com/
https://www.subdomain.domain.com/`
?